# Including node_modules during Express.js build

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, npm, build

i want to include its dependencies during Express.js compilation. Actually, what I want is to build like a react project. I don't want to deal with dependencies after building. Is there any way to do this?

I didn't try anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches to building your project into a single JS file, but I have found these two to be the best:

1. Webpack: With Webpack, you can build your project into a single JS file that includes all the dependencies. For more detailed information, please visit https://webpack.js.org/.
2. NCC: NCC is a framework that allows you to build your Node.js project into a single file. Sometimes, Webpack builds can become large, which may cause delays in application loading time. To avoid this issue, you can use ncc, which generates more compressed project builds. If your project requires a low-size build, then ncc is a good choice. You can find ncc documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/ncc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try Rollup https://rollupjs.org/introduction/#quick-start to bundle your code and dependencies into a single js file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).